# Disable concurrent flash video streaming

Tags: php, linux, flash

I am pretty sure I know the answer to this question but, out of curiosity and in the interest of putting forth a best effort, I have to put this out there.  I have a site that works on a subscription model.  I know that some users are sharing their accounts with many others.  To discourage that, I have used PHP to prevent more than one user from using an account at the same time by logging the first user out after a second user has logged in.  The problem is that there are long Flash videos on the site so a user could log in and start watching a video and, after video playback has been started, a second user could log in and watch and so on.  Is it possible to stop streaming to the first user if a second user has logged into the same account?  If so, how?

Thank you for any insight,

Orville

Comment: What's your streaming method?

Comment: This in not my area of competence and I am not sure if this even answers your question but the .flv files are being streamed with Flash.

Comment: Now that I think about it, I guess the video is not really being streamed as much as downloaded to the flash player in the client's web browser.  I am not using Media Server or anything.

Comment: Do the downloads go through a PHP or similar script or are they hotlinked directly like domain/path/file.flv?

Comment: I am not sure but here is an abridged version of the code:  <embed pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="sameDomain" src="http://www.sameurl.ca/Video.swf"/>

Answer (score 0):

I would try approach by special configuration of web server, so each page request is forked. Apache has MPM prefork module, that works that way.

On start of each PHP request, you will save PID of current process.

```
     $pid = getmypid();
```

Then save it to database to row with username as current process. If there was another PID stored already, use

```
    system('kill -TERM '.$pid);
```

I assume your server runs under the same user all the time, so it has right to kill another its process.

Now start to stream data, from start, to end.

```
     readfile($path);
```

When finished, set current users PID to NULL and finish.

It will allocate more resources on start, than threaded server would. But I think when streaming video file, more resources you save every second you stream, some fork at the beginning does not matter. What does matter is smooth and fast sending of video stream after it started, right?

I did not try it. It is possible apache would not be happy when you start killing his own processes from outside. I believe most users would watch only one movie at time, killing process should be rare enough. Feel free to try :)